# customizing sort label of responsive p:dataTable

Tags: sorting, primefaces, datatable

When using a basic Primefaces dataTable with sorting enabled, my table looks like this:

[image]

When making my screen size smaller, the responsiveness feature of the dataTable kicks in and removes the sorting labels from the dataTable itself, and adds a selection menu above the datatable, like this:

[image]

This is a very nice feature! However, I would like to change the label of 'Sort' and 'Ascending' (and also 'Descending').

I'm using PrimeFaces 6
How do I do this?

Comment: Search stackoverflow. Has been discussed before (and answered by me)

Comment: @Kukeltje Can't find it... I think I'm using the wrong search terms... Do you mind giving a hint?